# How do I write a custom validation formula that allows ONLY a date greater than a previous cell OR NA?

Tags: excel, validation

I am trying to validate data in cell C9. I basically need to do this:

Accept a date that is greater than that in cell C8 OR accept the letters NA.

Using this formula

```
=AND(C9>C8,C9="NA")
```

The date bit works, but I can type in any letters at all and it accepts it. Using **OR** brings the same result. I can't wrap my head around this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, when you are writing any text to `C9` cell it is greater than date (In excel text are also comparable like numbers). Try to detect `C9` is text or number (dates are nothing but number formatted as date) then apply logic. Use `IF()` function.

```
=IF(ISTEXT(C9),C9="NA",C9>C8)
```

[image]

Comment: That works a treat and I understand it, too. Thank you very much.